# Downloaded app on iPad, now I cannot download it on iPhone

Tags: itunes, iphone, ipad, ios-appstore

I downloaded [cinemagram](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCYQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fitunes.apple.com%2Fus%2Fapp%2Fcinemagram%2Fid487225881%3Fmt%3D8&ei=NuBpT-fhB6mf0QXCjaWJCQ&usg=AFQjCNGprsPRu5SvXkgtsz33icR4ZAwAkQ&sig2=_pYvv5ALW4y-Wc3CRZApeA) on my iPad2 running latest iOS5.1 - now I want to install it on my iPhone 4S running latest iOS5.1, the install is greyed out

I even deleted it on my iPad - that did not help.

**UPDATE** iCloud had instantaneously downloaded it onto my iPhone but on the other screen I never look at.

Comment: Just to double check - you are on iOS 5.x?

Comment: Is it possible that it's already installed? You can set iCloud to automatically download apps to multiple devices when they're purchased.

Comment: DUH - on the other screen. You are correct. Add as answer and I will accept it

Comment: @mplungjan OK, added

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be having this error because the app is already installed. If you have automatic downloads turned "on" for the App Store on your iPhone, iCloud will push the app to your phone if you buy it on another device.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you iPhone is compatible (iPhone 3GS, iPhone 4, iPhone 4S)?  If not, that's your problem.  That's the only reason I could think for it being greyed out.

**update:** Make sure iCloud didn't already install it on your phone.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. Yes all is iOS5.1 and I found the reason. I have all apps on one screen, iCloud downloaded it immediately onto another screen on my iPhone

Comment: yeah, i thought you checked to see if it was already installed...

Comment: Yeah - I will next time. Just a thinko.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to the App Store from your iPhone and iPad.
2. Tap on the Update tab.
3. Open Purchased and filter by Not on This iPhone/iPad.
4. A list of apps able to be re-downloaded will be shown. Tap on iCloud button to re-download and re-install from App Store in your iPad or iPhone.

Comment: This is super old - I'm on iOS 7 now on a 5S